# Ant copy text between two xml tags

Tags: ant

I am trying to copy an entire xml tag from a file and append it to another file.
I  have been messing arround with filterchains

```
<loadproperties srcFile="${dir}/file.xml">
              <filterchain>
<linecontainsregexp>
<regexp pattern="<assembly-descriptor> "/>
</linecontainsregexp>
              </filterchain>
</loadproperties>
```

I dont know how to form the regx pattern.

the source file looks some thing like this

```
<assembly-descriptor>
  <somelines>
   <somelines>
      <somelines>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

i need to copy the this entire tag to another file .

Answer (score 0):

Treating xml with line matching/regular expression matching will eventually fail.  Could you write a small program to do what you have described. Apparently there are [some task for xml](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/).

If you are okay with xslt, [xslt task](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Apache_Ant/XSLT) could help.

Comment: hmm not exactly m looking for ... but seems interesting will give it a try .